# Can PHP and mssql library select more than 256 characters from a varchar column?

Tags: php, sql-server

Is there a work around (other than changing the column type to a textfield) for SELECTing a large varchar field using PHP and mssql library? For instance a varchar(500). Does PHP really restrict the number of characters to 255? Is there a way to pull back more than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the PHP page, the problem seems to be the underlying database driver on Windows platforms. Varchar can only return < 255 characters. The work around is to cast the varchar to text within the sql SELECT statement.

Comment: Casting to VARCHAR(MAX) also seems to work if you need to use the keyword DISTINCT in your query.

Answer (score 5):

To cast a wide VARCHAR to TEXT in MS SQL:

```
SELECT convert(text,myWideField) FROM myTable
```

Where myWideField is the column being truncated and myTable is well... my table.

The result will be cast to TEXT returning more than 256 chars.

d.

Comment: If you want to use the original column-name you'll have to add `AS`. E.g.: `SELECT convert(text,myWideField) AS myWideField FROM myTable`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the freetds configuration.

In the server, edit /etc/freetds.conf

Change:

```
tds version = 4.2
```

to:

```
tds version = 8.0
```

See more in User Contributed Notes, [Mssql Functions Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php).

Comment: This definitely makes a positive difference, without code changes, which makes it a better solution in my opinion.

Comment: You beauty - version 7.0 worked for me, share the word to all suffering this legacy system hell!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change the values ​​of variables in the php.ini:

```
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```

But not works...

I changed the type of my column varchar (2000) to varchar (max).
This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about casting, I'd change the relevant field types to Text instead of Varchar.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing - but we weren't sure if that was going to break existing functionality. It didn't. But that's the work around in case you really can't change the type of the field you're working with.

Answer (score -1):

The cause may actually be MySQL rather than PHP...  Prior to MySQL 5.0.3 MySQL itself could only store 255 characters in a VARCHAR firled.  THis limit has been raised to 65535 in later versions.

Comment: Not MySQL, MS SQL. I'm not the one developing this - my team mate is. I'm just asking the question.