# SQL Server sp_helpconstraint constraint_keys field is truncated to 256 characters max in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, constraints, database-schema

I am writing a sQL parser to compare existing SQL database definitions to expected definitions via a DDL file.

I'm parsing constraints at the moment, but noticed that the constraint_keys column in the sp_help/sp_helpconstraint function(s) only seem to return 256 chars of the column in PHP/MSSQL.

[I see a related question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609386/can-php-and-mssql-library-select-more-than-256-characters-from-a-varchar-column) regarding 256 char varchar columns and how to get longer than this out of the PHP/MSSQL interface...

however, can I do this with the sp_constraint query? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the official [SQL Server PHP driver](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296173.aspx), they support all SQL server types properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I failed to mention that the environment is what it is... WE will eventually move to a PDO driver, possibly, but I can't be sure when that will happen and would like instead to write the equivalent query to sp_helpconstraint with that field casted to text if possible...

Comment: You need to use INSERT-EXEC to capture the result in a @table variable or #temp table, then you can select from that can CAST in the process.

Comment: Dude!!! Good call, but you should make that an answer to this question so I can give you credit (if i try it and it works that is... gimme a bit :D )