# PHP MSSQL VARCHAR 255 character issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

**Issue**: MSSQL queries against a VARCHAR(256+) field returns only 255 characters in PHP, regardless of the VARCHAR size being greater than 255.

I've seen references to a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609386/can-php-and-mssql-library-select-more-than-256-characters-from-a-varchar-column) and [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25544) where the workaround is basically to cast the VARCHAR to TEXT:

```
SELECT CAST(myField AS TEXT) AS myField FROM myTable
```

But this doesn't help if I have a bunch of queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

I mean, sure, I could look for all queries like that and do:

```
SELECT CAST(myField AS TEXT) AS 'myField2', * FROM myTable
```

And update the subsequent PHP variable from myField to myField2, but that is a pretty big task for the application I have.  Not to mention I'd have to do a lookup of all fields in all tables that have VARCHAR(256+) and then look in my PHP app for all queries affected.

We're running PHP 5.2.17 and I understand MSSQL isn't supported/developed on anymore.  I have seen the Microsoft-supported SQL Server driver [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098), but I would have to update my PHP version to 5.3.6 or 5.4.  I'm not entirely sure what that would entail if I did the upgrade.  Plus, we would have to change all mssql_connect() to sqlsrv_connect() and other functions from mssql to sqlsvr's version within our PHP app.

Does anyone know of any other workaround (like a newer DbLib C API that I can download from a trustworthy source) so I don't have to go modifying everything peppered throughout my PHP app?

Comment: i don't know about mssql, but will this work?
`SELECT CAST(* AS TEXT) FROM myTable` ? PHP doesn't care much about datatypes, so you won't have to cast to ints or dates in PHP. The only thing you would need to do then is do a global find for `SELECT *` and replace it by `SELECT CAST(* AS TEXT)`. IF my proposed query works of course :)

Comment: Interesting idea.  I haven't seen that before :) Unfortunately, it didn't work out so well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba562/2

Answer (score 7):

Edit `/etc/freetds.conf` to change the `tds version` setting to 8.0 (if your server is MS SQL Server 2000 or later) or 7.0 (if using MS SQL Server 7), uncommenting the setting if necessary.

Comment: Not sure why, but this does work for me. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: @XinChen: It seems that earlier versions of the protocol impose a 255-character length limit on VARCHARs.  More up-to-date versions don't.

Answer (score 1):

Start "MS SQL Managment Studio"

in main menu  Query\Query Options\  in this window choose  results\text  and at the end you will see "Maximum number of characters displayed in each column" by deafult it have 255, change it.

Comment: Hi @kibir, I tried your suggestion without any luck. I believe your suggestion only changes the settings on management studio's UI, not the PHP ODBC library.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question but I'm looking for the same answer today ;)

I tested this solution

```
select *, CAST(DESCRESTESA AS TEXT) AS DESCRESTESA from table_name
```

and it worked out very well